# Forcing all pages to be ssl except for the root page

Tags: nginx

I am currently using

```
location / {
  if ($ssl_protocol = "")
  {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
```

in my nginx conf. This successfully forces all pages to be https. However, I would like the root page and only the root page (aimed at index.htm) to be optionally http so that when the user goes to http://myserver.com it will not redirect to https. How can I do this?

(I am able to selectively not use ssl on certain subdirectories, by specifying their location, e.g., /nossl would allow http://myserver.com/nossl to be not ssl). If the user goes to http://myserver.com/somepage.htm I would want it to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the two `server` block approach for redirecting your users to `https`. You would then be able to specify a minimalist `http` site for the index page and its resources (if any). Something like this:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    root            /path/to/root;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location = / {
        index index.htm;
    }
    location = /index.htm { }
    location /js { }
    location /css { }
    location /img { }
}

server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    root            /path/to/root;
    ...
}
```